# Cant execute command line with codeigniter 3 mysql_init() error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, mamp, bitnami

I want to test PHP script that will execute a command line command. But I get the following error in the shell.

The site that I've design locally works perfectly

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_init() in /Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php on line 136

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity:    Error
Message:     Call to undefined function mysqli_init()
Filename:    /Applications/mampstack-5.6.19-0/frameworks/codeigniter/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 136

Backtrace:
```

I'm using Bitnami MAMP Stack 5.6.19.0 with Codeigniter 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need activate the `php_mysqli` extension in the `php.ini` file that controls the PHP CLI, its not the same one as controls PHP Under the web server.

From the terminal do

```
php -i
```

And look for the parameter `Loaded Configuration File` and `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` that will tell you which `php.ini` file to amend and where it lives.

If one does not exist, as I believe is the case on some installs, then you know where to create one by looking at the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` parameter.

You could start by copying your web server version into this directory, but do a quick sanity check on it as well

Comment: I get the following when I run the command. `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /opt/local/etc/php5 Loaded Configuration File => (none)`

Comment: Then you will have to make a `php.ini` in the `/opt/local/etc/php5` to configure the CLI environment to how you want it. For now that might just be to copy your web server version to there. Do a quick sanity check on what is in there though

Comment: Could you I've me some guidance to implement the solution that you are proposing.

Comment: Please note that you are using a bitnami stack. In order to load the stack environment, please execute `installdir/use_mamp`. Retest your issue, please!